# How to speed up Clickhouse query

Tags: database, optimization, indexing, clickhouse

I have a Clickhouse table defined as below:

```
CREATE TABLE default.my_table
(
    `timestamp` DateTime CODEC(Delta(4), ZSTD(1)),
    `service` LowCardinality(String) CODEC(ZSTD(1)),
    `operation` LowCardinality(String) CODEC(ZSTD(1)),
    `durationUs` UInt64 CODEC(ZSTD(1)),
    `url` String CODEC(ZSTD(1))
)
ENGINE = MergeTree
PARTITION BY toDate(timestamp)
ORDER BY -toUnixTimestamp(timestamp)
TTL timestamp + toIntervalDay(45)
SETTINGS index_granularity = 1024
```

I'm using this to store job info where `url` defines a url that's hit, `duration` is the time it takes to get a response, `operation` is the kind of op, `service` is the service making the call.

A lot of my queries are of the form `SELECT * from my_table where service='abc' and operation='xyz' and timestamp > ${2 days ago}`. This table has grown over time to be quite large:

```
┌────count()─┐
│ 3101352160 │
└────────────┘
```

And that means every query like the one above takes a long time *(sometimes > 1min)* ... What can I do to speed this up? I know I can probably index `service` but given that the data is not split evenly, I'm unsure it'll help (since Clickhouse uses indexes differently to Postgres/MySQL). Or will the best case be to change the partition key to `(toDate(timestamp, service)`?

What other levers can I use here to speed up my queries?

I want to basically reduce the number of chunks of data read by Clickhouse for processing using a valid index

Comment: In addition to the answer below where you make your PRIMARY KEY be (service, operation, timestamp), you should also not alter the default value of index_granularity. Set it to 8,192 so that you can skip more rows

Comment: This is a preexisting table. How do I change the index_granularity back to 8192?

Comment: tbh, I don't think you can change the granularity once the table is defined. If you can change it, I can't find any docs or examples of it. I'm guessing you will have to create a new table. If you don't change your current primary key, then at least try defining a projection like Robert mentioned below....that might really improve performance for you.

Answer (score 2):

As you mentioned, including `service` into the primary key is an option, i.e. `-toUnixTimestamp(timestamp), service` as primary key expression. With this, `SELECTs` with `service` as a filter condition will use the [generic exclusion algorithm](https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/optimize/sparse-primary-indexes#generic-exclusion-search-algorithm). However, `toUnixTimestamp(timestamp)` as the first primary key column sounds like it has high cardinality, so this will probably not be very efficient.

Another option is to use a "projection" with `service` (and possibly also `operation` and `timestamp`) as primary key column, i.e. a "mirror" table with alternative sorting. This will provide the best query performance but effectively double the storage size of your dataset.

Besides that, you could also create a [skipping index](https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/optimize/skipping-indexes) on `service`. They are useful whenever the values of `service` are clustered to some degree, e.g. correlate with timestamps (which unfortunately also sounds unlikely in your usecase).